# ffmpegのfilter_complexの中身を読み解きたい

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpegの-filter_complexの中身を読み解いて自分で応用したいと思っていますが、Googleで調べてもわかりません。

> -filter_complex '[v:0]hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,split=4[o1][o2][o3][o4],[o1]vpp_qsv=cw=1920:ch=1080:cx=0:cy=0[out1],[out1]split=3[r11][r12][r13],[r12]scale_qsv=w=1280:h=720[ro12],[r13]scale_qsv=w=960:h=540[ro13],[o2]vpp_qsv=cw=1920:ch=1080:cx=1920:cy=0[out2],[out2]split=3[r21][r22][r23],[r22]scale_qsv=w=1280:h=720[ro22],[r23]scale_qsv=w=960:h=540[ro23],[o3]vpp_qsv=cw=1920:ch=1080:cx=0:cy=1080[out3],[out3]split=3[r31][r32][r33],[r32]scale_qsv=w=1280:h=720[ro32],[r33]scale_qsv=w=960:h=540[ro33],[o4]vpp_qsv=cw=1920:ch=1080:cx=1920:cy=1080[out4],[out4]split=3[r41][r42][r43],[r42]scale_qsv=w=1280:h=720[ro42],[r43]scale_qsv=w=960:h=540[ro43]'

4Kでキャプチャーしたものをqsv処理するのですが、

1. hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64 とは何の処理をしている？
2. vpp_qsv, scale_qsvとは？
3. split=4[o1][o2][o3][o4]の4は何を指定しているのでしょうか？

このようなfilter_complexの中で使われる処理は皆さんは何を見て調べているのでしょうか。
ご教示いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 3):

> hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64 とは何の処理をしている？

[hwuploadフィルタ](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hwupload-1)によりGPUサーフェイスへの映像転送を指示しています。
[extra_hw_frameオプション](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n4.2.2/libavfilter/avfilter.c#L635-L636)はメモリ確保するフレーム枚数です。

> vpp_qsv, scale_qsvとは？

- [vpp_qsv](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n4.2.2/libavfilter/vf_vpp_qsv.c)：QSVを利用した汎用画像フィルタ。ここでは画像切り抜き(crop)処理を行っています。
- [scale_qsv](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n4.2.2/libavfilter/vf_scale_qsv.c)：QSVを利用した画像スケーリング（サイズ変更）フィルタ。

> split=4[o1][o2][o3][o4]の4は何を指定しているのでしょうか？

[splitフィルタ](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit)の分岐出力数です。入力映像を4分岐し、それぞれに o1,... o4 のラベルを付与しています。

---

> このようなfilter_complexの中で使われる処理は皆さんは何を見て調べているのでしょうか。

基本的には[公式オンラインマニュアル](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html)をあたりますが、必要に応じて[ソースコード](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/)も参照しています。
今回のようにハードウェア・アクセラレーション系はドキュメント整備が不十分なようですから、ソースコードを確認したほうが早いことが多そうです。

Comment: FYI: 日本語情報源ですと [ハードウェアデコーダ、フィルタ、エンコーダを組み合わせる](https://nico-lab.net/combine_hw_decoder_filter_encoder_with_ffmpeg/), [QSV フィルタの詰め合わせ VPP_QSV](https://nico-lab.net/vpp_qsv_with_ffmpeg/) がよくまとまっていると思います。ご参考までに。